# fetch api - 400 failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-rest-framework, fetch

Upon making a PUT request to my REST API, it returns a serialized response payload with a 400 Bad Request to the client.

```
{'vote': [ErrorDetail(string='Duplicate vote not allowed', code='vote_error')]}
(Pdb) c
Bad Request: /api/v1/questions/3/
[15/May/2021 09:41:24] "PUT /api/v1/questions/3/ HTTP/1.1" 400 39
```

However when the browser gets the response back it returns:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` while at the same time it has received the aforementioned response payload? What is causing this error to be raised when it has successfully hit the API and how can it be handled?

[image]

[image]

```
> c:\users\..\questions\views.py(266)put()->None
-> if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
n
(Pdb) rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'vote': [ErrorDetail(string='Duplicate vote not allowed', code='vote_error')]}
> c:\users\..\views.py(506)dispatch()
-> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class UserQuestionVoteView(APIView):

    throttle_scope = "voting"

    def put(self, request, id):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        account = UserAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        if account == question.user_account:
            return Response(data={
                'vote': "Cannot vote on your own question"
            }, status=400)
        try:
            stored_vote = QuestionVote.objects.get(
                account=account, question=question
            )
            serializer = QuestionVoteSerializer(stored_vote, request.data)
        except QuestionVote.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = QuestionVoteSerializer(data=request.data)
        finally:
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                question_vote = serializer.save(
                    account=account,
                    question=question
                )
                vote = serializer.validated_data['vote']
                if vote == "downvote":
                    question.vote_tally = F('vote_tally') - 1
                else:
                    question.vote_tally = F('vote_tally') + 1
                question.save()
                question.refresh_from_db()
                return Response(data={
                    'id': question.id,
                    'tally': question.vote_tally
                }, status=200)

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    vote = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate_vote(self, value):
        if self.instance and (value == self.instance.vote):
            raise ValidationError("Duplicate vote not allowed", code="vote_error")
        return value
```

Comment: It is a validation error. You may have a unique constraint imposed on "vote" field, and you are sending duplicate data. The error is not in the code you posted.

Comment: See APIView and its Serializer.  Not sure what the issue is given the API returns the desired response.

Comment: The validation error is raised in VoteSerializer - validate_vote(). You are sending the same value for "vote" as the one already in database. I don't see how you are getting the desired response if you are receiving a validation error with error code 400...

Comment: I'm trying to circumvent a user from abusing vote functionality. Preventing a user from upvoting/downvoting a topic multiple times in a row in the same direction. That is what was intended with raising that ValidationError thus if it happened I'd consider it a Bad Request. 

In other words, downvoting/upvoting 3 times in a row is not permitted. How do you propose handling this case?

Answer (score 0):

You've setup a `ValidationError` in your service to avoid user performing duplicated votes. So if triggered, your API will return a `400` error with your custom error message.

On the frontend, `fetch` will receive this error with the associated payload. What you need to do is handle this error with a `catch` (and handle the success with a `then`). Check out [this basic example](http://%20%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data)